# Regexp to match square bracket

Tags: regular-expressions

I've got this regexp that I found in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/get-the-content-between-the-nearest-square-brackets-in-a-string) thread that does not exactly working for me, I get `System.StringException: No match found`.

Basically, I want to get everything between [ ].

```
Pattern brackets = Pattern.compile('\\[');
string asf='[ { asdf } ]';
    Matcher matcher = brackets.matcher(asf);                
        system.debug(matcher.group(0));
```

**Edit:** I need to match curly braces too

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good blog post here for Regex usage:

[Using Regex in APEX](https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/extracting-strings-with-regex-in-salesforce-apex/)

It suits your need. I just modified the Regex to this: `\\[\\{([^}]*)\\}\\]` and was able to read content inside `[{ }]`.

**EDIT:**

Sample Code for the requirement:

```
string subject = 'this is a test [ {12312-D} ] email subject [dfasdfa]';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\[ \\{([^}]*)\\} \\]');
Matcher m = p.matcher(subject);
if (m.find()) 
{
   system.debug('\n\n@@ : '+m.group(1)+'\n\n'); 
}
```

Comment: Does not match if there is whitespace between [ and {

Comment: :-) .. It was pretty much straight forward. I've updated my answer with a sample code extracted and modified for your requirement from the same blog post.